# Django-Rest-Framework: How to post to foreignkey field using request.user for logged in user

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django rest Framework to make an api to be consumed by an android app. I have a model for events and Venue:

```
  class Event(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="%(class)s")
     title=models.CharField(max_length=256)
     venue=models.ForeignKey(Venue,related_name="%(class)s_venue")
     description=models.CharField(max_length=256)
     time=models.DateTimeField(max_length=256)
     event_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/event_pic/%Y/%m/%d",null=True,blank=True)

     album=models.ForeignKey(Album,null=True,blank=True,related_name="%(class)s_album")
     photo=models.ForeignKey(Photo,null=True,blank=True,related_name="%(class)s_photo")

     likes=GenericRelation(Like,null=True,blank=True)
     comments=GenericRelation(Comments,null=True,blank=True)
```

Here is my Venue model.

```
class Venue(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField(max_length=256)
     longitude=models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
     latitude=models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

I would like to post to the user field using  request.user and the venue field using name.Is it possible to do this and if so how do I do it.
Here are the serializers and views.

```
class WeddingList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):    

     queryset=Wedding.objects.all()
     serializer_class=WeddingSerializer


class WeddingDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
     queryset=Wedding.objects.all()
     serializer_class=WeddingSerializer





class VenueList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     queryset=Venue.objects.all()
     serializer_class=VenueSerializer

class VenueDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
     queryset=Venue.objects.all()
     serializer_class=VenueSerializer

class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           model=Venue
           fields=('name')

class WeddingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


      class Meta:
           model = Wedding
           excludes=('id',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your view:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    # Set here all fields that you need and that aren't already set
    obj.user = self.request.user
    obj.name = ...
```

and modify it to correspond to your needs :)

Comment: will 'name' be the name for the venue?

Comment: it depends in which class you are. The pre_save method has an obj parameter, that is the object that will be created. So if you're in VenueList, yes, obj will be a Venue

Answer (score 7):

Since Django REST Framework 3, the `pre_save` hook is not available anymore. Instead, override `perform_create`:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user, ...)
```

Comment: How do you get around it failing validation before perform_create is called because the user wasn't set in request.data?

Comment: I found that I could define the user in the serializer as user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()) which set the user to current user automiatically. Not always the solution, but good enough for my use case.